# Manually Refresh All Items for Calculated Field

Tags: list, calculated-column, refresh

Using SharePoint 2010.

Currently I have a column that is calculating the "Days left to respond" using the formula below.

```
=IF(IssueDate>0,IF(CurrentSPIResponseDate="",ResponseDueDate-NOW(),""),"")
```

This is working fine in terms of the calculations, however, I need a method to update the calculated values in this column.  I know that the calculated fields are updated at the save time and not at render time from digging around.

I am ok with manually refreshing the data as long as it is something that can be done quickly (as in not 1 item at a time).  If there was a select all option and then a mass edit/save, that would work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I would like to avoid a lot of complications as I am not in IT and I am limited due to security protocols on even my own laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best bet is to add a new temporary field and open your list in data sheet view and then paste some dummy value from excel to fill all the cells. Your calculated field should update and then once done you can delete the temp field as it is no longer needed.

Tal

Comment: Just to make sure I understand. Are you saying to do this in the datasheet view? Steps: 1) create a new field "Dummy"
2) Assuming I have 500 records, I paste in 500 dummy values under the "Dummy" field.
3) Delete "Dummy" field Is this correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, good luck